# How to exclude STREAM_SYSTEM from REMOTE_SUBMIX

Tags: android, audio, android-source, audioflinger

I am writing an app to record the audio from the device, using REMOTE_SUBMIX.
According to this [PAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#REMOTE_SUBMIX), it is said that

***Certain streams are excluded from the remote submix, including STREAM_RING, STREAM_ALARM, and STREAM_NOTIFICATION. These streams will continue to be presented locally as usual.***

Now I want to exclude STREAM_SYSTEM also, but I cannot find where this policy/strategy is defined in the AOSP souce code or any configuration file.

Does anyone know any clue about it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the audiopolicy service code (unless you are on an Intel device which uses routing code based on Parameter Framework, then it's in a configuration file).

I think the code you are interested in is here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-8.0.0_r1/services/audiopolicy/enginedefault/src/Engine.cpp#477

audiopolicy works this way: first it finds "strategy" for a stream using `Engine::getStrategyForStream` function, then it goes into `Engine::getDeviceForStrategyInt` to pick a device for this strategy.

It seems that both `STREAM_SYSTEM` and `STREAM_MUSIC` use the same `STRATEGY_MEDIA`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-8.0.0_r1/services/audiopolicy/enginedefault/src/Engine.cpp#180

So you would have to change something if you want to exclude system sound, but leave music playback on remote submix.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer. This is close to what I am looking for. I noticed engine.cpp when I posted this question. Can you point out which config file shall I modify? I saw that RING and ALARM are belonging to STRATEGY_SONIFICATION and NOTIFICATION belongs STRATEGY_SONIFICATION_RESPECTFUL. These two will not be mixed in remote_submix. Shall I just change this engine.cpp and move STREAM_SYSTEM to STRATEGY_SONIFICATION?

Comment: As I've said, it's not in a config file, unless it's a device made by Intel.  Yes, you can start with that and see whether it works as you expect, and whether it breaks anything else.  Unfortunately, it's hard to say whether your idea would work prior to trying it.

Comment: I tried to modify the engine.cpp to change the strategy, and replace the libaudiopolicyenginedefault.so on my target board. I saw the debug log I have added but it still does not fix the problem. Any idea about the potential reason?

Comment: I would suggest  uncommenting `//#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` and `//#define VERY_VERBOSE_LOGGING` in the beginning of Engine.cpp. This will provide you with a rich set of logging messages about the internals of the policy engine. You need to figure out why does it selecting the remote submix device for your stream type.